# How to Store a File to Parse Server with fs

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, parse-server

I was having trouble with this, though it probably is a rookie issue. I want to store some file at `../images/icon.png` as a File object in my database. I had trouble accessing the actual data and storing it properly. The documentation for Parse.File says you can access the data as

```
1. an Array of byte value Numbers, or 
2. an Object like { base64: "..." } with a base64-encoded String. 
3. a File object selected with a file upload control.
```

but I couldn't figure out how to actually do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was

```
let iconFile = undefined;
  const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'images/icon.png');

  fs.readFile(filePath, 'base64', function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      iconFile = new Parse.File('icon', {base64: data});
    }
  });
```

I was getting errors where the path wasn't pointing to the image correctly, so I used node's path (as in `require('path')` to get it to point correctly.

This code should work for any file type, as far as I can tell.